# How can I start my app with all permissions allowed on Android 6

Tags: android, io, permissions

I check if user has permission, but just wanna do that when he deny on Android Options. When he install my app, how can I set all permissions on. I saw that happens on Google I/O 2015 app.(You can turn off permission, but when you install, this permissions are already on).

Thanks!

Comment: This would be a pretty terrible way to do things. When someone installs your app they would see a never ending list of things your app "needs" access to and would likely scare off any potential downloaders. Not to mention you shouldn't be listing permissions for things you don't actually need. There are 100+ individual permissions. There's no need to make the user have to define all those. You should be doing that in your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2015 Google IO app targets API version 22, which means that it will not use the runtime permissions model, even if running on a device running Android 6.0 (API 23) and up. In this case, permissions are still granted at install time, but users can still go in and manually disable permissions.

If you are targeting API 23+, you **must** use the new runtime permissions model. No permissions will be granted to your application at install time.

Comment: Thanks! 
I'm using runtime permissions.
But you answer my question! =D

Answer (score 0):

I hope you speak Spanish, otherwise, use a translate tool. Android 6.0 changed the way permission works, dangerous permissions are disabled by default even if you define them in the manifest.

Check my post here, http://androidenespannol.blogspot.com/2015/11/solicitar-permisos-en-tiempo-de.html

Best regards